# Template not found by heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I just deployed my Django site on Heroku but I'm getting `TemplateNotFoundError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010548+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010548+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = get_response(request)
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010549+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010550+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010551+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010551+00:00 app[web.1]:     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010552+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/workoutcal/views.py", line 51, in redirect_to_calendar
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010553+00:00 app[web.1]:     return calendar(request, year = today.year, month = today.month)
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010554+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/workoutcal/views.py", line 56, in calendar
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010554+00:00 app[web.1]:     return prompt_login(request)
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010555+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/workoutcal/views.py", line 286, in prompt_login
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010556+00:00 app[web.1]:     return render(request, 'workoutcal/prompt_login.html')
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010556+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010557+00:00 app[web.1]:     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010558+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010559+00:00 app[web.1]:     return template.render(context, request)
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010559+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 63, in render
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010560+00:00 app[web.1]:     reraise(exc, self.backend)
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010561+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 84, in reraise
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010561+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise new from exc
2018-01-17T16:17:41.010565+00:00 app[web.1]: django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: workout/base.html
```

I already did what is recommended in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11768200/3128156) answer:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)
```

but it didn't help.

What is the problem here?

PS: Everything works fine on my local machine. (**UPDATE: This isn't true because I'm using another settings file locally. My bad.)**

**UPDATE**:

Changed to this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    }

]
```

Same problem remains.

**UPDATE 2**:

I put this in the settings:

```
path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
print("\n\n\n\n\n\nHERE'S THE PATH: "+str(path))
```

it produced this:

```
HERE'S THE PATH: /app/workout/templates
```

I don't know if this is where the template file resides in Heroku. How can I check?

Here's where the base.html is located in my project:

[image]

So that would be `workout/templates/workout/base.html` (not counting the root project folder). Comparing the two paths, they don't seem to point to the same thing. The first one that is actually being checked is lacking another step `workout` to be in the same folder as `base.html`. Is this the problem? How do I fix it?

Comment: What's the django version? Could you ensure that the `template_name` in the right view points to existing template in `templates` directory?

Comment: 2.0. Not sure what your second question means, mate.

Comment: In django `settings.py`, `TEMPLATES[x]['DIRS']` is the list of directories where django should look for templates. The exact template which it's looking for is named in a view by `template_name` (as for CBV). Therefore if your structure is alike: `templates/sth/my_template.html` means, you should configure your view like this: `template_name=sth/my_template.html`. Could you ensure that it's right?

Comment: Note that the traceback mentions `prompt_login` - you may find that if you log out on your local machine then you’ll get a similar error.

Comment: That's possible, I was mistaken in saying that it works on my local machine, changed the OP.

Comment: @PiotrPeczek, it looks correct to me:  `template_name = 'workoutcal/calendar.html'`

Comment: I don't understand your project layout from the screenshot. It looks as if Django can find your template `workoutcal/calendar.html` but can't find `workout/base.html`, but your screenshot doesn't show where `workoutcal/calendar.html` is.

Comment: Since your settings is a directory instead of a file, you may have to add another `os.path.dirname()` when settings `BASE_DIR` so that it is set to the project directory.

Comment: Added a new screenshot that shows all templates.

Comment: As I said in the answer, if you keep your templates in the inner `workout` directory, then you may need to adjust the value in `DIRS`, e.g. `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "workout", "templates")`.

Answer (score 1):

Had this issue and found that on my local mac the filename of the template is case in-sensitive while on Heroku it's case sensitive.

So it was working on my machine but was throwing `TemplateNotFound` on Heroku.

`components/react/ReactDOM.jsx` is the same `components/react/ReactDom.jsx` in jinja with Mac  but not in jinja with linux (Heroku)

Answer (score 0):

The question you linked to is years out of date. Since Django 1.8 you should be using `TEMPLATES`, not `TEMPLATE_*` settings.

Add the `templates` directory to the `DIRS` option.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        ...
    }
]
```

This assumes that your `templates` directory is in the project directory (the one containing manage). It looks as if your templates directory is in the inner `workout` directory (the one containing settings). Therefore you would want to use `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "workout", "templates")` in `DIRS`.

If you want to keep the templates in the inner `workout` directory, then another option is to add `workout` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`. Then the app directories loader will find your workout templates and you won't need the entry in `DIRS`. Even if you do this, it would be useful to get your `TEMPLATES` working using the `DIRS` approach. For example if your `BASE_DIR` is wrong, then it might cause you problems in other places.

Comment: I did as you said, but it didn't change anything. I put the exact changes I made in an update on the question.

Comment: Then you'll need to do more debugging. Where is the `workout/base.html` template located? What does `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")` evaluate to? Do they match. Perhaps this is a workout/workoutcal naming problem, as with many of your questions.

Comment: I did some debugging and posted the results in an update.

Comment: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")` assumes that the templates directory is in the project directory. It looks as if you have your templates in the inner directory instead.

Comment: You need to tweak `DIRS` setting (and possibly your `BASE_DIR` as I mentioned in a previous comment, so that it matches the template directory `/path/to/workout/templates/` (ignore the final `workout/base.html` since that's what you specify in your `{% extends %}` tag. It would be easier to get this working on your local environment first, then you'll get absolute paths that you can compare, instead of `/app/.../`.